# javascript templates truncating some data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-templates

MovieName = "This is a sample movie name text;"

```
  <tr>
       <td> ${MovieName} </td>
       <td> <input type="text" id="mytext" size="15" value=${MovieName} /> </td>
  </tr>
```

When I run this, the first one prints:

```
This is a sample movie name text;
```

second one prints:

```
This
```

I would like to know if I am missing some thing basic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<input type="text" id="mytext" size="15" value="${MovieName}">
```

Note the `"` before and after ${MovieName}.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't surround the value in quotes, attribute values that are not quoted cannot have spaces in it.

```
 <td> <input type="text" id="mytext" size="15" value="${MovieName}" /> </td>
```